# convert a long string into a Tstringlist

Tags: delphi, pascal, lazarus

hello guys I have the following string A type string.

A = 'flagA=0,flagB=0,flagC=1'

B:Tstringlist.

I want to convert it into Tstringlist in order to see if the flagC is set to 1 by inspecting B.Values['flagC'].

perhaps i need to split the string under '=' and ',' ?
Any other ideas are welcome thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
B := TStringList.Create;

B.Delimiter := ',';
B.DelimitedText := 'flagA=0,flagB=0,flagC=1';

ShowMessage(B.Values['flagC']);

cars.Free;
```

Comment: Why not just use the `CommaText` property instead?

Comment: yes, it was to show a more generic solution

Comment: For a more general case, setting StrictDelimiter to True might also be necessary, depending on the input.

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7UMx.png)

you can use that code

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
b,a:string;
i:integer;
list:TStringList;
begin
list:=TStringList.Create;
a := 'flagA=0,flagB=0,flagC=1';
for i:=0 to length(a) do
 if a[i]='f' then
 begin
  b := copy(a,i,7);
  list.Add(b);
  ListBox1.Clear;
  ListBox1.Items.Assign(list);
 end;
end;
```

you can use edit1 like this

```
a:= edit1.text //that consider the contain as string
```